# Why does my ajax call fire only once when submitting forms loaded with @HtmlRenderPartial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an index page that i load with two partial views. on each partial view loaded there is an ajax call that filters the content by date. The problem is that the ajax only fires successfully once and subsequent form submission just causes a total refresh of the page i.e the ajax is not firing. I moved each script to a separate file and referenced it in a bundle that i called in my Layout page. Trying again yielded the same result i.e the ajax event is firing only once, when the submit button is clicked again,nothing happens. Below is my code

```
Index.Cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout ="~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>TRANSACTIONS</h2>
@Html.Action("IndexGrid", "Transactions")
<h2>BREAKDOWN</h2>
@Html.Action("LoanBreakDown", "Transactions")
<div class="ajaxModal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
```

IndexGrid.cshtml

```
<form action="/transactions/index" method="post" id="filterByDate">
            <td colspan="3">
                <label>START:</label> <input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label>END:/label> <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" />
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
       <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-default submit" />
            </td>
        </form>
```

LoanBreakDown.cshtml

```
<form action="/transactions/LoanBreakDown" method="post" id="searchloan">
    START: <input type="date" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" />
    END: <input type="date" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" />
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

GridDateFilter.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filterByDate").submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#TransactionTable").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Transactions/IndexGrid",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#TransactionTable").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

BreakdownDateFilter.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchloan").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        //$(".loading").html("Processing your request...");
        $("#loadbreakdown").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Transactions/LoanBreakDown",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadbreakdown").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The GridDateFilter.js is responsible for the IndexGrid.cshtml while the BreakdownDateFilter.js is responsible for the LoanBreakDown.cshtml. Please note that both views are loaded into the main page i.e the index.cshtml page with @Html.RenderPartial and the scripts are included in the Layout page after the call to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i finally fixed this. After googfing around for a while in the developer tool of chrome, Though i dont understand too much of javascript, i noticed that the form that is responsible for the search feature is embedded inside the div that i am replacing with the result of the ajax post, as a result, the dom has changed and when i submit again, its not targeting that same form again. The fix was to move the form out of that div and Eureka! it worked.